# Subtotal at cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data

I have two entities, Journal and Accounts. The relationship is one-to many: Journal has only one Account. Account has many journals. I want to show the total for each Account based on its Journals, but I don't know how.  Currently the total I am getting for each account is the same:

In my UITableView (Accounts.m) I have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    XbAccountsN *cell = (XbAccountsN *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XbAccountsN" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = xbAccountsN;
        self.xbAccountsN = nil;
        GMAccount *awCuentasy = (GMAccount *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.cnAlias.text = awCuentasy.cnAlias;
        NSDecimalNumber *saldoAc = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.0"];
        for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
            NSLog( @"Looping");
            NSDecimalNumber *objectExpenseNumber = [object valueForKeyPath:@"journals.@sum.pzAmount01"];
            balanceC = [balanceC decimalNumberByAdding:objectExpenseNumber];
        }
        NSNumberFormatter* bf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
        [bf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        cell.cnSaldo.text = [bf stringFromNumber: balanceC];
        [bf release];
```

I get the same amount for each account, even if I have just two accounts, and several journals related to each account. How can I present the correct balance for each account? Could you please help me?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide all your method code. I guess you are setting your variable value in the if (cell==nil) block. Maybe.

Comment: Vincent, thank for your time.  I put the whole code for the method.  I'm very new in xcode, some let me know if you need something else.

Comment: This logic belongs in your model in the first place. Why does it need to be recomputed every time the table view asks for a cell?

Comment: MArk, I didn't get you (sorry but I'm Finance guy moving IT/BT). I'm not very use to all terms. Let me clarify.  The user selects an account from the UITableView (Accounts), then, he creates a journal (through a button in the nav bar). Once the journal was input, he goes back the first table (Accounts). The balance for each account is expected to be updated.  My understanding is that the UITableView through its delegates run this kind of update.

Comment: Mark thx for your reflection. It was a great hint to eliminate "for" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It seems **you are setting your cell label in the if (cell == nil) block**. It is not correct. Notice that in a tableView the **cells are recycled** and when a sufficient amount of cells are created the block is no longer called because old cells are available in the recycling queue. Ok. Here the right way below. (check the  syntax, I wrote it here).

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    XbAccountsN *cell = (XbAccountsN *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    if (cell == nil) {
        // Init new cell from nib archive (assuming the cell is the top most object in your xib)
        cell = (UITableviewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XbAccountsN" owner: nil options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0];
    }

// Calculate your sum for the given awCuentasy
    GMAccount *awCuentasy = (GMAccount *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.cnAlias.text= awCuentasy.cnAlias;
    NSDecimalNumber *saldoAc = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.0"];
    for (NSManagedObject *object in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]) {
            NSLog( @"Looping");
            NSDecimalNumber *objectExpenseNumber = [object valueForKeyPath:@"journals.@sum.pzAmount01"];
            balanceC = [balanceC decimalNumberByAdding:objectExpenseNumber];}
    NSNumberFormatter* bf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
        [bf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        cell.cnSaldo.text= [bf stringFromNumber: balanceC];
        [bf release];
}

return cell;

}
```

Comment: I having an error at cell = (UITableviewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"XbAccountsN" owner: nil options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0]; "Incompatible pointer types assigning to XbAccountsN from UITableViewCell*..  am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. I assume that your xib contains only a UITableViewCell. If it's not the case, extract your cell definition in a separate xib as a unique object and call [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"xibOfMyCell" owner: nil options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0] to init a new cell according the xib.

Comment: You are correct. I only have one UITableviewcell with four UILAbel.  One is the balance, the rest are for information (account description, etc.)

Comment: Could you insert a log
NSLog( @"Strange object is : %@ , "[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourCellXib" owner: nil options:nil] objectAtIndex: 0] ); Before your cell = ... to see the object returned.

Comment: I put the NSLOG as you indicated me, but the app stop at that line and was not possible to continue; however I have the following information from the debugger window: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x6b4a670> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xbAccountsN.'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x1a01052 0x1b92d0a 0x1a00f11 0xb46032 0xab7f7b 0xab7eeb 0xad2d60 0x3c591a 0x1a02e1a 0x196c821 0x3c446e 0x3c6010 0xc33c 0x23fe0f 0x240589 0x22bdfd 0x23a851 0x1e5301 0x1a02e72 0x23ab92d 0x23b5827 0x233bfa7 0x233dea6 0x233d580 0x19d59ce 0x196c670 0x19384f6 0x1937db4 0x1937ccb 0x18ea879 0x18ea93e 0x1a6a9b 0x2822 0x2795)
terminate called throwing an exceptionSingle stepping until exit from function __kill.  Can I give additional code to replace this NSLOG?

Comment: Vincent, I got it.  I eliminated the for statement and kept the Uitableviewcell as it was; however, your suggestion was very helpful to trigger a reflection.  You're good man.

Comment: Vincent, sorry I can't vote.  I'm trying to gain more "points". Once again. thx!

Comment: Check your xib outlets. An outlet seems wrong or the class of your Owner Object in the xib is wrong. Or send me your project ;)

Comment: Oh nice. You fix it ! Congratulations !!